# Pywinauto not recognizing window if backend='uia'

Tags: python, pywinauto

I am using pywinauto for Automating CANDelaStudio application. In that when I clicked on export button new Save As window appear. I wanted to connect it with backend="uia". but if I use "uia" backend I get  "pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError". if I use backend "win32" is working.
but I want to use some check boxes in Save As window which is not visible in "win32" backend.
Please help me in this!!!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"win32" and "uia" backends provide different hierarchy. In "win32" all windows are top level, while in "uia" auxiliary windows are children of main window. Just call `.dump_tree()` for main window specification or try to use [py_inspect](https://github.com/pywinauto/py_inspect) which can switch backend.

Comment: thank you. later i understood i can connect to child window from main window class.

Comment: Is there any reason that after application update I can no longer use uia backend?

Comment: It's a question to application developers or GUI framework developers who can disable accessibility features in the app by default or intentionally.